# Python "import" performance query

Tags: python, import

Well, this query struck my mind when someone pointed out to me that importing a package using **import package** gives more code readability. Is this actually true? I mean when using this statement as compared to **from package import x, y, z**, isn't there any overhead of importing the entire package?

Comment: i think you misunderstood what the guy meant, i think he meant to compare `import package` to `from package import *`. Wildcard imports should be avoided, as they "pollute" the namespace.

Comment: okay... that clarifies it further...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't expect any performance difference. Whole package will be loaded anyway.

For example:

```
# load dirname() function from os.path module
>>> from os.path import dirname

#the os.path.basename() was not imported
>>> basename('/foo/bar.txt')
NameError: name 'basename' is not defined

# however, basename() is already available anyway:
dirname.__globals__['basename']('/foo/bar.txt')
```

Comment: In both cases whole packages is loaded anyway. The difference is only in what gets to the namespace.

Comment: that means if I use from ... import ..., if I could **somehow** get around this namespace thing, I would be **(theoretically speaking)**, able to access everything in that package?

Answer (score 3):

The performance will be same either way. The entire module is compiled, if needed, and the code executed, the first time you import a module, no matter how you import it.

Comment: +1. The different forms of the `import` statement influence only what names end up in the importing module's namespace, not how much of the module gets loaded into memory.

Answer (score 3):

Using the point notation is always less performant than importing a function directly and calling it, because the function does have to be searched in the modules dictionary. This counts for every `getattr` operation.

For example when appending items to a list:

```
lst     = []
for i in xrange(5000):
    lst.append(i ** .5 * 2)
```

This is faster:

```
lst     = []
append  = lst.append
for i in xrange(5000):
    append(i ** .5 * 2)
```

This *can* make a real heavy difference.

```
>>> def bad():
...     lst     = []
...     for i in xrange(500):
...         lst.append(i ** .5 * 2)
>>> def good():
...     lst     = []
...     append  = lst.append
...     for i in xrange(500):
...         append(i ** .5 * 2)
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("bad()", "from __main__ import bad", number = 1000)
0.175249130875
>>> timeit("good()", "from __main__ import good", number = 1000)
0.146750989286
```

Comment: I think he meant a performance penalty to import, not to access.

Comment: Let me guess, gentoo user?  0.06µs per call is not what many people would consider a heavy difference.  Certainly not, when you consider how much more readable my_well_named_variable.append(item) is.

Comment: The absolute difference is irrelevant, the _percentage_ different is what matters, and that is significant. If you had a program like above but with 5 billion iterations instead of 500, you'd care about a 25% speed increase.

Answer (score 1):

Which is more readable

```
from os.path import split, join
```

then a bunch of `split` and `join` calls that would accidentally be read as the string methods of the same name, or

```
import os.path
```

then referencing them as `os.path.split` and `os.path.join`? Here, it's clear they're methods dealing with paths.

Either way, you have to actually load the whole module. Otherwise, things that you imported that depended on other things in the module you **didn't** import wouldn't work.